# How to get RecyclerView to show bubble when you can't scroll any farther?

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, material-design

In normal Material applications, when you scroll all the way to the bottom of a list and then try to keep scrolling, you see a colored bubble come up from the bottom of the screen, like so:
[image]

I'm using a `RecyclerView` and it only displays the bubble if I fling to the end. If I'm already at the end, it does nothing. Do I need to add something in the XML to get the behavior I want? It does seem that `ListView`s get this behavior by default.

If it's relevant, my `RecyclerView` is a direct child of the `CoordinatorLayout` that is the top element of the Activity.

Do note that the app in the screenshot is not the same as the app I'm currently working on.

Comment: That is expected behaviour within a coordinator layout. Why is this so important?

Comment: I guess it's not *that* important, I just wish it was the other way because of my own personal taste. In addition, it provides visual feedback to the user that they can't scroll any farther.

Comment: that's just it, RecyclerView is bare bones, ListView comes packaged, there are many things default in ListView that don't exist in RecyclerView.

Comment: This should be an inbuilt function of RecyclerView. But, sadly not available. Same requirement i got.

Comment: @JonMcClung : you can set scrollBar to give user the indication that how much is scrolled.